# status is pending in network section and preview is blanked that's why data is not showing in postman . How can i resolve this issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-fullstack

```
const SignUp= ()=>{
    const[name,setName] = useState("");
    const[email,setEmail] = useState("");
    const[password,setPassword] = useState("");

    const collectData = async () => {
        console.warn(name,email,password);
        let result = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/register",{
            method:'post',
            body: JSON.stringify({name,email,password}),
            headers:{
                'Content-Type' :'application/json'
            }
        })
        result = await result.json();
        console.warn(result);
    }
```

After running this status is pending in network section and preview is blanked that's why data is not showing in postman .
How can i resolve this issue.